# Convert tree to list of lists

Tags: python, list, tree

I have a tree structure, something like:
Company -> Department -> Roles ->

I have a triple for loop-structure like this:

```
for company in self.Companies():
    cName = company.Name()
    for dept in company.Departments():
        dName = department.Name()
        for role in dept.Roles():
            rName = role.Name()
            roleID = role.ID()
```

The .Name() function returns a dept name like Android-Sales. Companies can zero or more departments.

So far the above is all I have. I am  trying to develop this so I can get a list of lists:
Ideally this is what I would like. If something repeats, the next item in list should leave it blank. Or it might not have a field, in that case leave it blank too.

> [
>     ['Google', 'Android-Sales', 'Marketer', 'A123'],
>     ['','Google-Play','Developer', 'A435'],
>     ['','','Tester','A125'],
>     ['','','','A126'],
>     ['My Small Company','','Super Role','A123'] 
>     ]

Or this would work too...

> [
>     ['Google', 'Android-Sales', 'Marketer', 'A123'],
>     ['Google','Google-Play','Developer', 'A435'],
>     ['Google','Google-Play','Tester','A125'],
>     ['Google','Google-Play','Tester','A126'],
>     ['My Small Company','','Super Role','A123'] (Here "My Small Company" has no > departments. 
>    ]

Each inner list should be of length 4.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
tree = {"Google":{"Android":"yes", "Nexus":"no"}}
list_of_lists = []

def listbuilder(sub_tree, current_list):
    for key in sub_tree:
        if isinstance(sub_tree[key], dict):
            listbuilder(sub_tree[key], current_list + [key])
        else:
            list_of_lists.append(current_list + [key] + [sub_tree[key]])

listbuilder(tree,[])

print str(list_of_lists)
```

Output:

```
[['Google', 'Nexus', 'no'], ['Google', 'Android', 'yes']]
```

Comment: Instead of `type(sub_tree[key]) == dict` it would be more Pythonic to use `isinstance(sub_tree[key], dict)` to allow any suitable mapping object to be used to hold the tree data-structure.

Comment: There are too many septs to do this for. I gave a small sample. In reality there can be 50 companies, with 1-50 departments in each.

Comment: Septs? I'm not sure what that is. Also, I didn't give you a full solution, just an idea of how a full solution could be implemented. This solution should scale nicely to a dict of 50 companies with 50 departments each.

Comment: What do you mean there are too many departments? This solution should scale to virtually any size.

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I needed to insert JSON files in a structured way into a database. Based on the solution described by [@Gillespie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2516916/gillespie), I was able to convert the file hierarchy into lists of lists.

The following script expects to read a JSON file whose list of items is initially identified by the parent key "value". Here is a simple example of the `data.json` file.

##### JSON File

```
{
    "value":
    [
        {
            "A": 0,
            "B": 1,
            "C": 2
        },
        {
            "C": {
                "E": 3,
                "F": 4
            },
            "D": [
                {
                    "G": 5
                },
                {
                    "H": 6
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The following script reads a JSON file and turns it into tuple lists to be inserted into a database. Remember to remove special characters before creating tables and columns in the database.

##### Python Script

```
import json


def dict_to_list(sub_tree: dict, current_list: [str], items_list: [[str]]) -> [[str]]:   
    try:  # Tree branches.
        for key in sub_tree:
            if isinstance(sub_tree[key], list):
                for sub_item in sub_tree[key]:
                    dict_to_list(sub_tree=sub_item, current_list=current_list + [key], items_list=items_list)
            elif isinstance(sub_tree[key], dict):
                dict_to_list(sub_tree=sub_tree[key], current_list=current_list + [key], items_list=items_list)
            else:
                items_list.append(current_list + [key] + [sub_tree[key]])
    except:  # Tree leaf.
        items_list.append(current_list + [str(sub_tree)])
            
    return items_list
  
  
def json_data_to_samples_list(json_data: dict, data_key: str = 'value', column_sep: str = "_") -> [[(str, str)]]:
    samples_list = []
    
    for parent in json_data[data_key]:
        column_value_tuples = []
        
        for child in dict_to_list(sub_tree=parent, current_list=[], items_list=[]):
            column = column_sep.join(child[:-1])
            value = child[-1]
            column_value_tuples.append((column, value))

        samples_list.append(column_value_tuples)
  
    return samples_list



def main() -> None:
    json_file_path = "data.json"

    with open(json_file_path, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        json_data = json.load(file)

    samples_list = json_data_to_samples_list(json_data=json_data)

    print(f"\nExtracted {len(samples_list)} items from the JSON file:")

    for idx, parent in enumerate(samples_list):
        print(f"\n>>>>> Child #{idx}:")

        for child in parent:
            print(f"\t\t{child}")

    print()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

##### Expected Output

```
Extracted 2 items from the JSON file:

>>>>> Child #0:
                ('A', 0)
                ('B', 1)
                ('C', 2)

>>>>> Child #1:
                ('C_E', 3)
                ('C_F', 4)
                ('D_G', 5)
                ('D_H', 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69180000/16109419), you might also want to convert a JSON file to tuples that can be inserted into a database. In that case, you can use the following [package](https://pypi.org/project/dict2dataframe/).